# Marker Cluster styles

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Is there a way I can change what style is applied to a marker cluster? I know the default is based on the size of the cluster, I want to change it.

Background: I have a markers with several colors for computer availability, red=offline, green=available, yellow=unavailable. I was able to change the number in the clusters by using the setCalculator function and having it set the number by counting the number of markers with an icon set to green. Is there a way to make it so if there are so many green markers in a cluster i can change the cluster color that way? Also is there a way to change that based on the level of zoom?

IE: default zoom level

```
if #avail < 2 => set red
if 2 < #avail < 5 => set yellow
if #avail > 5 => set green
```

I've tried this:

```
markerClusterer.setCalculator(function (markers, numStyles) {
      var index = 0;
      var count = markers.length;
    var avail = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<count;i++){
      if (markers[i].icon == "icons/available.png"){
          avail++;
        }
    }

    switch(true) {//change index based on number of available computers
        case (avail == 0)://red
            index = 3;
            break;
        case (0 < avail < 3)://yellow
            index = 2;
            break;
        case (avail >= 3)://blue/green
            index = 1;
            break;
    }
      //index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
      return {
        text: avail,
        index: index
      };
    });
```

Comment: 1. Do you want to change the style of a "marker cluster" or a "cluster marker"? - 2. What have you tried?

Comment: I thought the style applied to the cluster marker and marker cluster is an area that doesn't have style.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but in your question you wrote **... change the cluster color ...**

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a function that does what you need. The function will check the number of green/colored markers in that cluster and also the zooming level(the if elseif conditions should do that) and accordingly override the previously set icon for the cluster. You will be calling this function at the end of your `setCalculator()`. I dont expect this to be tough, give a try and post the code what you tried if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out
My switch was bad and the logic for yellow was messing it up
:

```
if(avail == 0){
   index=3;
}
if((0 < avail)&&(avail < 3)){
   index=2;
}
if(avail >= 3) {
   index=1;
}
```